# How to use CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes for Ignite Cache

Tags: java, caching, high-availability, ignite

I am following the code for the running SQL queries in the Ignite cache, but am able to fully realize the use of the CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes API.

I am following the only help that I could find at the ignite site.

The documentation [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-query-configuration-by-annotations) says to use 
***CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(MyKey.class, MyValue.class).***

Now lets say in the Person class

```
@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private long id;

@QuerySqlField
private String firstName;
```

Which are the parameters that I should be passing in the setIndexedType method?

Answer (score 2):

`setIndexedTypes` takes an even number of parameters. Every odd parameter corresponds to a key type, and every even - to a value type. In your case you should probably use `id` parameter as a key, so you should call it this way:

cacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Person.class);

Javadoc for `setIndexedTypes` method contains a pretty good explanation of this method: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setIndexedTypes(java.lang.Class...)

**UPD:**

There will be registered a table in SQL for each pair of parameters that you provide to `setIndexedTypes` method.

Your SQL entities will map to cache records and they will have `_key` and `_val` columns in addition to the ones that you configured as QuerySqlField-s. So, you should specify types of keys and values that will be used in cache for each table.

You can refer to this page for more information: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/dml#basic-configuration

Comment: So in case, lets say I have two indexes on the class  Person
       @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        private long id;

        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        private String orgId;

My indexTypes should be --

        cacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Person.class, String.class, Person.class);

is this correct?

Comment: @frewper no, actually key type doesn't depend on indexes. Even if you make other fields indexed, then setIndexedTypes call will stay the same. I added some info about it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it will be

```
cacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(KeyType.class, Person.class)
```

where KeyType is the type you use for keys while calling `cache.put(key, person)` or `insert into Person(_key, ...) ...`
Please refer to [this documentation section](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.2/docs/dml#section-insert)